# DesiredSize of a button and radio button in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need to measure the DesiredSize or ActualHeight/Width of a button (and radio button) without actually putting it onto the visual tree but I keep getting back non-sense values. This same approach works when measuring other controls such as TextBlock.

```
        var button = new Button
        {
            Content = "Hello World",
            FontSize = 15
        };

        button.Measure(new Size(maxWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
        var height = button.DesiredSize.Height;
        var width = button.DesiredSize.Width
```

I'm getting back 21px for height and 0px for width. Any idea why I'm getting 0 back for width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to measure the DesiredSize or ActualHeight/Width of a button (and radio button) without actually putting it onto the visual tree but I keep getting back non-sense values.

If you assign a string value to `Button.Content`, the value will be assigned to the inside TextBlock through Binding in runtime, which happens after the `Button.Measure` (You can see this by adding the button to the page and check the LiveProperty Explorer):
[image]

So you get the wrong desired size.

As a workaround, you can create a TextBlock and assign this TextBlock to the button:

```
var tbContent = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "Hello World",
    FontSize=15
};
var button = new Button
{
    Content = tbContent,
};
var h= button.DesiredSize.Height;
button.Measure(new Size(200, double.PositiveInfinity));
var height = button.DesiredSize.Height;
var width = button.DesiredSize.Width;
```

Then you will get the correct Size of this button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this isn't possible. You're measuring the button before it has loaded its template.

I can only suggest doing something like this:

```
var but = new Button();
but.Content = "Hello";

var popup = new Popup();
popup.Child = but;
popup.IsOpen = true;
popup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

but.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(but.RenderSize);
    popup.IsOpen = false;
};
```

But it's kind of hacky, and the button won't load until some later time, making this whole process asynchronous which might be difficult to manage.